# Are the quotes in the Anima rulebook legit?

Tags: history-of-gaming, anima-beyond-fantasy

I like the quotations in the Core Rulebook, and have sourced some of them (like the Seneca one and the one from the *Count of Monte Cristo*). Others, however, are harder to track down or are inaccurately attributed (like Anacharsis). My favorite of the quotations is the one which is attributed to Jose Gnecco Laborde, who I think, after some Google-fu, was a Spanish author. I think part of my problems in authenticating the quotations is that they have been translated from their original languages into Spanish *then* into English.

- Did the developers attempt to use only real-world material for these quotations?
- Why were these quotations and sources picked?
- Why were these quotations included at all?

The quotations from the book are presented below, but I understand that it is a bit much to ask from a Q&A site to sources all of these. A case-by-case confirmation or denial of each quotation's authenticity could count as an answer, but I'm more interested in the answers to the questions above.

## Quotations

> To be born is to begin to die
>   **—Theophile Guatier**
>
> Soul for the human
>   Anima for the beast
>   Yet always we say
>   Blessed be the animas of purgatory
>   **—Jose Gneco [*sic*] Laborde**
>
> Everybody thinks that having talent is a matter of luck
>   Nobody thinks that luck could be a matter of talent
>   **—Jacinto Benavente**
>
> The only man who never makes a mistake
>   Is the man who never does anything
>   **—Teddy Roosevelt**
>
> Among so many changes in human affairs
>   Only death is certain
>   Nonetheless all lament
>   This thing that fools no one
>   **—Seneca**
>
> All men are made of the same clay
>   But not from the same mold
>   **—Trinidad**
>
> It is always good to know about everything
>   **—Lao Tse**
>
> If the Porcupine were a little smarter, it wouldn't need all those needles
>   **—A. Graf**
>
> Never count how many times you have fallen
>   but the strength with which you arise
>   **—Anacharsis**
>
> It is astonishing how much strength the soul can infuse into the body
>   **—W. von Humboldtu**
>
> Once I dreamt my soul abandoned my body
>   I could fly and look inside the hearts of men
>   The only thing I could not do was wake up
>   **—Montaigne**
>
> A man's power doesn't consist of what he can do himself, but what he can will others to do
>   **—Joshua**
>
> It's all in the mind
>   **—H. Durán**
>
> You never know what lies ahead before you when you wake up in the morning
>   **—Clariton Howard**
>
> Ignorance leads us into error, and error leads us into learning
>   **—Agustus**
>
> He who directs is a man in need of others
>   **—Paul Valery**
>
> A land without ruins is a place without memories
>   A place without memories is a land without history
>   **—Abraham J. Ryan**
>
> The darkness envelops all of us
>   But while the wise man stammers against a wall
>   The ignorant man remains in the center of the chamber
>   **—A. France**
>
> One by one all of us are mortals
>   Together we are eternal
>   **—Quevedo**
>
> All the harmony in the world is made up of discordance
>   **—Seneca**
>
> The truth... that fragment of death...
>   Sometimes I would prefer to live in the shadows
>   **—Fedor Kavsow**
>
> Hell starts with others
>   **—Goethe**
>
> Men fear the very same Gods they have invented
>   **—Lucano** [*sic*? maybe Luciano De Crescenzo?]
>
> Divinity runs through our veins
>   Because, in the end, we are like Gods
>   **—Emerson**
>
> All of us have our reason to exist
>   All of us have are needed in the world...
>   **—Angel Osorio**
>
> The sleep of reason produces monsters
>   **—Goya**
>
> There is no need to know danger in order to fear it
>   Indeed, it may be observed that it is usually unknown perils that inspire the greatest terror
>   **—Alexandre Dumas**
>
> I don't care up to where our vision reaches
>   In our future I can see many horizons...
>   **—Barnabas**

Comment: Can you include these quotes in your question?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about establishing the legitimacy and source of quotes and has nothing to do with role playing games

Comment: How is it functionally different than http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/was-chaosiums-founder-first-to-buy-a-copy-of-dd ? Or http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6718/has-white-wolf-ever-faced-bankruptcy ?

Comment: I took a crack at this. I hope it's okay. Feel free to revert. I *like* this pitch, but the questions felt buried. That this potentially leads to an analysis of the use of real-world quotations in role-playing game texts, a history which is traceable, is worthwhile.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer difference in expertise. Those questions can be answered by an rpg hobbyist from cultural knowledge. Verifying the authenticity of quotes, however... well, I'll let the team the answer needed to do this speak for how far outside the realm of rpg expertise that activity is.

Comment: @doppelgreener That makes sense:  the issue isn't that the *subject* of the question is off topic, but that the expertise required to *answer* the question is not RPG expertise (unless someone happened to be or know an Anima developer, or be an Anima history buff, which is less likely than for a major system like D&D), so the question is off-topic for this site by SE policy, since RPG experts are not necessarily experts in other fields.  Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer That's it, with one difference: it's off topic by _our own_ policy, not SE policy. See the heading _"this is not the right site for questions about"_ in our [on-topic help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). That arrived [as a reaction to real-world research questions](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1604/are-campaign-research-questions-on-topic-part-two).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disregarding the quotes that come in variations due to different translations, then **Yes**, the quotes are real.

I teamed up with a Professor of Literature from Roskilde University and a theologian from Trinitatis to reach the ones you can't just get to with regular google-fu.

> Did the developers attempt to use only real-world material for these
>   quotations?

Well, I found none of these quotes to be outside the realm of real world events, so yes.

> Why were these quotations and sources picked?
>   Why were these quotations included at all?

I would simply say, because they fit. The Call of Cthulhu series had some marvelous use of mixing reality with fiction in order to make the material more "real", and to make them more rememberable.

It serves both to tie the story-world to the real world, where everything suddently becomes more relatable. It also shows that these concepts (like monsters) are things humankind has dealth with for a long time, regardless wether there are actual monsters in their world.

For absolute specifics, only the editor/writers can tell you why each were picked individually. But usually these are harvested during research, and kept because the team felt it had something to it that would enhance the information or experience given by the main text.